# HTB overlimits traffic BW

Tags: controls, token, bucket, traffic, hierarchical

I am using TC Linux HTB to limit traffic bandwidths in the egress interface.

For it, I've set the following instructions on a linux container:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth2 root handle 1: htb default 12 
tc class add dev eth2 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 100mbit ceil 100mbit 
tc class add dev eth2 parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate 40mbit ceil 100mbit  
tc class add dev eth2 parent 1:1 classid 1:12 htb rate 1bps ceil 100mbit
```

Without configure any filter, when I realize an iperf3 with a throughput of 200M that passes the container, the traffic goes through the default queue (12). However, instead of having 100 Mbps as set, I obtained 73-75 Mbps.

Why this can occur?

Answer (score 1):

If HTB is overlimiting traffic bandwidth, it means that the allocated bandwidth for a particular class or queue is insufficient to handle the incoming traffic. This issue can be addressed by adjusting the HTB configuration to allocate more bandwidth or prioritize critical traffic.
https://serverfault.com/questions/254535/traffic-shaping-on-linux-with-htb-weird-results

Comment: Thank you for the fast support. If I reduce the class rate and ceil to kbps, the problem is still the same. It never reaches the ceil rate. I've also increased the txqueuelen and it still working in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that "1bps" does not work very well, changing it to "8bit" works better. Also, it is important to note that these instructions were applied over a virtual machine and it works better on local.